# using now() function for comparison in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.There is a 'shows' table in my database which stores show schedules of movies in a cinema. There is a field named 'showtime' of DATETIME type(I am using phpmyadmin).For e.g. a showtime is stored as 2014-11-03(yyyy-mm-dd).Now I am trying to retrieve those rows where showtime is greater than the current date. I've tried this:

```
 $this->db->select('Show_ID,showtime');
 $this->db->where('showtime>',now());
 $query = $this->db->get('shows');
```

It is not working.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this ``$this->db->where('`showtime` > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);`` to use MySQL's `NOW()` function.

Comment: Either what @RocketHazmat said, or use PHP's `time()` function.

Comment: @Shomz: That's basically what CodeIgniter's `now()` does.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Comment: You could also try: `$this->db->where('showtime>', date('Y-m-d'));`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right, sorry, never used the date helper before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the date in the correct format to compare with MySQL DATETIME type.

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('showtime >', date('Y-m-d'));
```

You can also try using MySQL's `NOW()` function:

```
$this->db->where('showtime > NOW()', NULL, FALSE);
```